# Firebase authStateChanges Stream doesnt update

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, bloc

whenever a user creates an account, signs out or signs in into my app, the authStateChanges stream doesnt update unless I hot restart, and when i re-run the app it returns the correct widget.

## Widget

```
class WrapperView extends StatelessWidget {
  const WrapperView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<AuthBloc, AuthState>(
      buildWhen: (previous, current) => current != previous,
      builder: (context, state) {
        if (state is Unauthenticated) {
          return const LoginView();
        }
        if (state is Authenticated) {
          return const HomeView();
        }
        return const Scaffold(
          body: Center(
            child: Text('Something went wrong...'),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

## Bloc

```
class AuthBloc extends Bloc<AuthEvent, AuthState> {
  AuthBloc({required this.authRepo})
      : super(
          authRepo.currentUser != null
              ? Authenticated(authRepo.currentUser)
              : const Unauthenticated(),
        ) {
    on<_AppUserChanged>(_onUserChanged);
    on<AppLogoutRequested>(_onLogoutRequested);

    _userSubscription = authRepo.authStateChanges.listen(
      (user) => add(
        _AppUserChanged(user),
      ),
    );
  }
  late final StreamSubscription<User?> _userSubscription;

  final FirebaseAuthRepository authRepo;

  void _onUserChanged(_AppUserChanged event, Emitter<AuthState> emit) {
    emit(
      event.user != null
          ? Authenticated(authRepo.currentUser)
          : const Unauthenticated(),
    );
  }

  void _onLogoutRequested(AppLogoutRequested event, Emitter<AuthState> emit) {
    try {
      unawaited(authRepo.logOut());
      emit(const Unauthenticated());
    } catch (e) {}
  }

  @override
  Future<void> close() {
    _userSubscription.cancel();
    return super.close();
  }
}
```

## Bloc State

```
abstract class AuthState extends Equatable {
  const AuthState();

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [];
}

class Authenticated extends AuthState {
  const Authenticated(this.user);
  final User? user;

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [user];
}

class Unauthenticated extends AuthState {
  const Unauthenticated();
}
```

## Bloc Event

```
abstract class AuthEvent extends Equatable {
  const AuthEvent();

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class AppLogoutRequested extends AuthEvent {
  const AppLogoutRequested();
}

class _AppUserChanged extends AuthEvent {
  const _AppUserChanged(this.user);

  final User? user;
}
```

## authStateChanges Stream

```
  Stream<User?> get authStateChanges => _firebaseAuth.authStateChanges().map(
        (fbUser) => return fbUser,
      );
```

I would like to note that i have tried to use `userChanges()` stream and it did not fix the issue.

another note is that i call the register and login methods in separate blocs.